# Small popup agreement window in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, popup, alert

I need to ensure the user agreement to the app policies and link to this policies in the same small popup window that ask for the user agreement.

I thought I might be able to use a regular alert:

```
return Alert(title: Text("Agreements Confirmation"), message: Text("\nIn order to use the app you need to agree with our policies"), primaryButton: .default(Text("Agree")) {

              //Let the user access                                                                    
           }
                                                        
 }, secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Reject")))
```

But it's seems like you can't use links in alerts whatsoever.

I can always use .sheet or .popover but it's just not fitting the normative requirement of a small window that hosts very limited length of text.

How can I achieve a small popup window that can contain a link and two buttons for "Accept" and "Reject" in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0):

use a custom alert

```
struct MyAlertView<Presenting>: View where Presenting: View {

@Binding var isShowing: Bool
    
    let presenting: () -> Presenting
    
    var message: String
    var url: URL
    var onAcceptClicked: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            self.presenting()
                .blur(radius: self.isShowing ? 4 : 0)
                .disabled(self.isShowing)
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                VStack (alignment: .center) {
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(width: 0, height: 120)
                    
                    VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 2){
                        Image(systemName: "doc")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            .offset(x: 0, y: 35)
                            .zIndex(1)
                        MyLink(message: message, url: url)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Rectangle().foregroundColor(.white).cornerRadius(15).opacity(1))
                            .padding(30)
                            .shadow(radius: 8)
                        
                    }
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: self.accept){
                            Text("Accept", comment: "")
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        }
                        Divider()
                            .frame(height: 1)
                        Button(action: {
                                isShowing.toggle()
                        }){
                            Text("cancel", comment: "")
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width * 0.60, maxHeight: 100)
                    .background(Rectangle().foregroundColor(.white).cornerRadius(15).opacity(1))
                    .shadow(radius: 8)
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())//per far cliccare anche al centro
            //.offset(x: 0, y: -60)
            .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.isShowing.toggle()
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func accept() {
        onAcceptClicked()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.2, execute: {
            self.isShowing.toggle()
        })
        
    }
}

extension View {
    func myAlertView(isShowing: Binding<Bool>, message: String, url:URL, onAcceptClicked: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        MyAlertView(isShowing: isShowing, presenting: { self }, message: message, url: url, onAcceptClicked: onAcceptClicked)
           
    }
}
struct TestView: View {
            
    @State var isShowing: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
                          
        Button("click me") {
            isShowing.toggle()
        }
        .myAlertView(isShowing: $isShowing, message: "link message", url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!, onAcceptClicked: {
        print("Agreements accepted")})
           
    }

   
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}

public struct MyLink: View {
    
    var message: String
    var url: URL
    
    public var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            Link(message, destination: url)
        } else {
            Text(message)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .underline()
                .onTapGesture {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                }
            
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work well for me, I am using SwiftUI 1 in order to support iOS 13 devices too. It's interfering with the position of the controls of the hosting view (even when the message isn't presented yet) . Also, the window is poping up in the bottom right corner of the screen.

Comment: Had to take down "  .modifier(fillButtonCircle(foregroundColor: .white, backgroundColor: .blue, dimension: 15))" and use "Button(self.message){
                            UIApplication.shared.open(self.url)
                        }" instead of Link, but I am not sure if this is the cause

Comment: please, check the new MyLink struct to have iOS 13 support